# Get doughnut chart series give zero result when it is available

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a docx file that contain only two charts, one is Pie chart and the other is Doughnut chart, like this:

[image: chart in docx screenshoot]

I am about to modify those chart data as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54723360/3444734):

the problem is:

```
pieChart.getChartSeries ().size (); // give me 1
doughnutChart.getChartSeries ().size (); // give me 0
```

I think the doughnutChart series should be available, since I have checked the doughnutChart workbook (`doughnutChart.getWorkbook ();`) is valid (showing the right data) and the doughnut chart also displayed properly on Ms. Word app.

The question is why `doughnutChart.getChartSeries ().size ();` give me zero when I expect it to give me one. Is it a bug, or I should treat pie and doughnut chart differently? if that's so, how can I get series from doughnut chart and modify it?

**=== UPDATE ===**
I am giving up with getting doughnut chart series since it not directly supported by the library.
I tried to just replace the doughnut data all together with a new one using a piece of code that look like this:

```
private void replacePiasChartData (
            String title,
            XWPFChart chart, // the doughnut chart get from XWPFDocument
            SourceData data)
{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook ();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet ("sheet");
    chart.setWorkbook (workbook);

    chart.setTitleText (title);
    int rowNum = 1;
    sheet.createRow (rowNum).createCell (0).setCellValue ("1st Qtr");
    sheet.getRow (rowNum).createCell (1).setCellValue (data.getChartValue ());

    rowNum++;
    sheet.createRow (rowNum).createCell (0).setCellValue ("2nd Qtr");
    sheet.getRow (rowNum).createCell (1).setCellValue (100d - data.getChartValue ());

    XDDFDataSource<String> category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory
                .fromStringCellRange (sheet, new CellRangeAddress (1, 2, 0, 0));

    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> value = XDDFDataSourcesFactory
                .fromNumericCellRange (sheet, new CellRangeAddress (1, 2, 1, 1));

    XDDFChartData chartData = 
                new XDDFPieChartData (chart.getCTChart ().getPlotArea ().addNewPieChart ());

    chartData.addSeries (category, value);
    chart.plot (chartData);
}
```

The chart is updated with a new data on it, however the initial chart is still there (as inner doughnut chart), is there any way to remove it, so that the replace process done properly?. I think I should remove the initial chart data, however I could not find any way yo do that.

Currently the chart look like this:
[image: double doughnut chart]

**=== UPDATE II ===**
It's solved by getting the series of the doughnut chart using additional class that behave quite similar with the Pie Chart.

Comment: The answer is simply that [XDDFChart.getChartSeries](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.html#getChartSeries--) does not provide doughnut chart until now. Only bar chart, line chart, pie chart, radar chart and scatter chart are provided. See source code https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.java?view=markup#l371.

Comment: @AxelRichter, thank you for that.
However, is there any work around to get the series?
Or at least, do you know a way to remove the initial series? so that when I create a new series (using `chartData.addSeries (category, value)`) it won't display double doughnut chart?

Comment: No help possible without having a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your side.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, I have updated the question. Could you please look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go clearly would be providing a `XDDFDoughnutChartData`. This is simple because it not really much differs from the `XDDFPieChartData`. Only difference is usage of `CTDoughnutChart` instead of `CTPieChart`.

Following is the implemention derived from https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFPieChartData.java?view=markup:

```
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

import org.apache.poi.util.Beta;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTAxDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumDataSource;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDoughnutChart;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTPieSer;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTSerTx;

@Beta
public class XDDFDoughnutChartData extends XDDFChartData {
    private CTDoughnutChart chart;

    public XDDFDoughnutChartData(CTDoughnutChart chart) {
        this.chart = chart;
        for (CTPieSer series : chart.getSerList()) {
            this.series.add(new Series(series, series.getCat(), series.getVal()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setVaryColors(boolean varyColors) {
        if (chart.isSetVaryColors()) {
            chart.getVaryColors().setVal(varyColors);
        } else {
            chart.addNewVaryColors().setVal(varyColors);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public XDDFChartData.Series addSeries(XDDFDataSource<?> category,
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> values) {
        final int index = this.series.size();
        final CTPieSer ctSer = this.chart.addNewSer();
        ctSer.addNewCat();
        ctSer.addNewVal();
        ctSer.addNewIdx().setVal(index);
        ctSer.addNewOrder().setVal(index);
        final Series added = new Series(ctSer, category, values);
        this.series.add(added);
        return added;
    }

    public class Series extends XDDFChartData.Series {
        private CTPieSer series;

        protected Series(CTPieSer series, XDDFDataSource<?> category,
                XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> values) {
            super(category, values);
            this.series = series;
        }

        protected Series(CTPieSer series, CTAxDataSource category, CTNumDataSource values) {
            super(XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromDataSource(category), XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromDataSource(values));
            this.series = series;
        }

        @Override
        protected CTSerTx getSeriesText() {
            if (series.isSetTx()) {
                return series.getTx();
            } else {
                return series.addNewTx();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setShowLeaderLines(boolean showLeaderLines) {
            if (!series.isSetDLbls()) {
                series.addNewDLbls();
            }
            if (series.getDLbls().isSetShowLeaderLines()) {
                series.getDLbls().getShowLeaderLines().setVal(showLeaderLines);
            } else {
                series.getDLbls().addNewShowLeaderLines().setVal(showLeaderLines);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public XDDFShapeProperties getShapeProperties() {
            if (series.isSetSpPr()) {
                return new XDDFShapeProperties(series.getSpPr());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setShapeProperties(XDDFShapeProperties properties) {
            if (properties == null) {
                if (series.isSetSpPr()) {
                    series.unsetSpPr();
                }
            } else {
                if (series.isSetSpPr()) {
                    series.setSpPr(properties.getXmlObject());
                } else {
                    series.addNewSpPr().set(properties.getXmlObject());
                }
            }
        }

        public long getExplosion() {
            if (series.isSetExplosion()) {
                return series.getExplosion().getVal();
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public void setExplosion(long explosion) {
            if (series.isSetExplosion()) {
                series.getExplosion().setVal(explosion);
            } else {
                series.addNewExplosion().setVal(explosion);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected CTAxDataSource getAxDS() {
            return series.getCat();
        }

        @Override
        protected CTNumDataSource getNumDS() {
            return series.getVal();
        }
    }
}
```

Used in code the following will work for pie charts as well as fpr doughnut charts now:

Word template:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class WordChangeChartDataPieOrDoughnut {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "TEMP_Chart_Simple.docx"; // has template chart having 1 series, 4 categories
  String filePathNew = "New_Chart_Simple.docx";

  Object[][] data = new Object[][] { // 1 series, 4 categories
   {"", "Clothing sales"}, // series titles
   {"Trousers", 123d}, // category 1
   {"Shirt", 345d}, // category 2
   {"Skirt", 180d}, // category 3
   {"Blouse", 180d} // category 4
  };

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filePath));

  XWPFChart chart = document.getCharts().get(0);
  XSSFWorkbook chartDataWorkbook = chart.getWorkbook();
  String sheetName = chartDataWorkbook.getSheetName(0);
  XSSFSheet chartDataSheet = chartDataWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName);

  XDDFChartData chartData = null;
  if (chart.getChartSeries().size() == 1) { // only one chart data
   chartData = chart.getChartSeries().get(0); // pie chart or other supported chart
  } else if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartList().size() == 1) { // only one doughnut chart data
   chartData = new XDDFDoughnutChartData(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartList().get(0)); //doughnut chart
  }

  if (chartData != null) { 
   if (chartData.getSeries().size() == 1) { // exact one series

    int rMin = 1;
    int rMax = 4;

    // set new category data
    XDDFCategoryDataSource category = null;
    int c = 0;
    for (int r = rMin; r < rMax+1; r++) {
     chartDataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(c).setCellValue((String)data[r][c]); // in sheet
    }
    category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); // in chart

    // series 1
    XDDFChartData.Series series1 = chartData.getSeries().get(0);
    c = 1;
    // set new title
    String series1Title = (String)data[0][c];
    chartDataSheet.getRow(0).getCell(c).setCellValue(series1Title); // in sheet
    chartDataSheet.getTables().get(0).getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(c).setName(series1Title);
    if (chartDataSheet.getTables().size() > 0) {
     if (chartDataSheet.getTables().get(0).getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().size() > c)
      chartDataSheet.getTables().get(0).getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnList().get(c).setName(series1Title);
    }
    series1.setTitle(series1Title, new CellReference(sheetName, 0, c, true, true)); // in chart

    // set new values
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = null;
    for (int r = rMin; r < rMax+1; r++) {
     chartDataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(c).setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]); // in sheet
    }
    values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(chartDataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(rMin,rMax,c,c)); 
    series1.replaceData(category, values);
    series1.plot(); //in chart

   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePathNew); 
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, this is the best solution. It's clean solution that leverage the existing solution.  
Thank you for this.